# PHP's equivalent to Excel's MROUND function, rounding to nearest multiple

Tags: php, excel, rounding

Excel has the [MROUND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mround-function-c299c3b0-15a5-426d-aa4b-d2d5b3baf427) function which rounds a number up/down to a given multiple.

```
=MROUND(600, 400) //--> 800
=MROUND(14,4)     //--> 16
=MROUND(0.5,2)    //--> 0
```

What is the equivalent function for PHP?

If there is none, how would you do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve the same effect by dividing by the denominator, rounding it, then multiplying it again by the denominator. Eg:

```php
function roundTo($number, $to)
{
    return round($number/$to, 0)* $to;
}

echo roundTo(87.23, 20); //80

echo roundTo(600, 400) // 800
echo roundTo(14,4)     // 16
echo roundTo(0.5,2)    // 0
```

Comment: That's clever! Accepted this one instead of the previously accepted one because of the explanation edit. Makes it a better answer overall. fineaddition.jpeg

Answer (score 6):

The PHPExcel implementation of MROUND()

```
function MROUND($number,$multiple) {
    if ((is_numeric($number)) && (is_numeric($multiple))) {
        if ($multiple == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        if ((SIGNTest($number)) == (SIGNTest($multiple))) {
            $multiplier = 1 / $multiple;
            return round($number * $multiplier) / $multiplier;
        }
        return 'NAN';
    }
    return 'NAN';
}   //  function MROUND()

function SIGNTest($number) {
    if (is_bool($number))
        return (int) $number;
    if (is_numeric($number)) {
        if ($number == 0.0) {
            return 0;
        }
        return $number / abs($number);
    }
    return 'NAN';
}   //  function SIGN()
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic logic is this:

```
$number= 600;
$unit= 400;
$remainder= $number % unit;
$mround = ($remainder < $unit/2) ? $number - $remainder : $number + ($unit-$remainder);
```

You'll need to validate your inputs to be sure they are numbers and to avoid dividing by zero.